# JPA Multi join NAMED Query Results to POJO

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA named query like below, not a native one.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "SummaryQuery", query="SELECT p.dId , p.hashedId ,p.lanCode , p.markCode, Address "
        + "FROM ProfileSummary p "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH Address Address ON Address.id.dId = p.dId "
        + "WHERE p.dId = :dId ")
```

This query fetchs data from two tables using left join.
Since it is a custom query JPA returns output in Object array and not the POJO I expect. Below is the mapping for SQL Result set. I am not sure, if the below mapping is getting used.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "SummaryQuery",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = ProfileSummaryPojo.class,
                columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "dId"),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "hashedId"),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "lanCode"),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "markCode")
                }
        )
    )
```

As this is custom query and oneToMany mapping, I want just one DB HIT not two separate queries.
That is the reason I wrote custom query. Now the issue is it returns result set as list of Object.
How to get it in POJO.

Thanks in advance.